# Is it possible to scroll Treeview's column content, not column window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I have a window with Treeview widget and a column. If I add enough nodes so that node's text extends beyond window's width, it'll not be possible to scroll horizontally unless I change *column width* to make it wider than the *window width*.

Here's what I mean:

[image: I should be able to scroll horizontally so I can accomodate for the node's text.]

I should be able to scroll horizontally so I can accomodate for the node's text, but the horizontal scroll bar is disabled.

However, if I manully resize the column itself, I'll be able to scroll until I reach the column's right border.

[image: Notice that scrollbar accomodates for the column width, not the text.]

Notice that scrollbar accomodates for the column width, not the text, the text was left behind.

```
self._tree_scrollbar_x = ttk.Scrollbar(self._tree_frame, orient='horizontal', command=self._tree.xview)
self._tree.configure(xscrollcommand=self._tree_scrollbar_x.set)
self._tree_scrollbar_x.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.E, tk.W))
```

There is a `resize` property, but that only changes whether the column resizes automatically with the *window frame/border*.

I know this question has been asked before without a solid answer, so this just might be the limitation of Tkinter/Ttk.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: maybe get the selected items width and whatever padding is used to move it off the left side and set width to that in a bind event ?